# Strange quirk in c loop while trying to printf progress indicator

Tags: c, loops

I have a slow running loop that can take an hour or more so I want to print a progress indicator.  I'm using the following kind of code.

```
for (int i=0; i<=j; i++)
{
    pass[0] = 'A' + i;
    printf("%c", pass[0]);
\\Some slow running code omitted for brevity
}
```

If I use this code it will spit out ABCD...Z (or stop when it finds the answer) when then entire loop completes which defeats the purpose of having a progress indicator.  But if I include a new line character \n in the printf statement, it will print ABCD out progressively while the loop is running.  That is the behavior I want but unfortunately it adds a line break between each letter.

I tried to add a space and that didn't work because it won't print until the entire loop is done.  I even tried using the putchar() function and that behaved the same as the printf() function where I cannot get it to progressively print out the letters unless I insert a new line between each character.  Can anyone explain this behavior or what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: `stdout` is buffered, it takes some time until the characters are printed on screen. When `printf` sees a newline, it flushes the buffer, that's why you see that. If you don't want the newline, just add `fflush(stdout)` after the `printf`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`stdout` is a buffered stream, that means that characters are going to be stored
in the buffer first before they are actually printed on screen.

The `printf`-family of functions however flush the buffer when it encounters a newline, that's why you
mostly see `printf` lines that end with a newline.<sup>1</sup>

Using `fflush` you can flush the buffer yourself. So, I you don't want the
newline and also want to see the text right away, use `fflush(stdout)`:

```
for (int i=0; i<=j; i++)
{
    pass[0] = 'A' + i;
    printf("%c", pass[0]);
    fflush(stdout);
}
```

will solve your problem.

---

**Footnotes**

<sup>1</sup>I believe this only applies for `stdout`, I think I read somewhere a
long time ago, I can't find the source anymore. But I've found this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4201325/1480131